# Solve permutation matrix equations of the form: $X^T A X = B_1$ and $X A X^T = B_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, matrix-equations

I have a hard time solving the following two matrix equations for unknown permutation matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$:
$$X^T A X = B_1$$
$$X A X^T = B_2$$
where, $A$, $B_1$ and $B_2$ are all $n \times n$ symmetric permutation matrices such that $B_1 \neq B_2$ in general. The solution $X$ may not be symmetric.

If this can be solved, can we say anything about the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: If $B_1=I\neq B_2$, then there is no such $X$ because $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not similar. Note that $X^T=X^{-1}$. So, if the above equations hold, then $B_1$ and $B_2$ must be similar.

Comment: Moreover, $A,B_1,B_2$ must all have the same cycle structure (as permutations).

Comment: I think this is better phrased as a question about (conjugacy of) permutations.

Comment: $A$, $B_1$, and $B_2$ are permutation matrices for product of disjoint transpositions (or possibly empty product, which gives $I$). Of course, similar, so the number of transpositions must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Two permutations are conjugated in $S_n$ iff they have same spectrum (as matrices).
Since $A,B_1,B_2$ are symmetric, they are a product of $k$ (the same $k$ for all) disjoint transpositions.

Let $A,B_1,B_2$ be such matrices.
Then there exist $X,Y\in S_n$ s.t. $X^TAX=B_1,Y^TAY=B_2$.

EDIT. Although the OP does not seem very passionate about what I write, I give below a method to solve part of the problem for matrices of order up to $30$.

Does there exist $Z\in S_n$ s.t. $Z^TAZ=B_1,ZAZ^T=B_2$ ?

and what is the number of solutions if there are any ?

We suppose -for example- that $k$ is maximum. Note that -up to a permutation- we may assume that $A=[[1,2][3,4]]\in S_4$ (if $n$ is even) and $A=[[1,2][3,4]]\in S_5$ (if $n$ is odd).

We consider the algebraic system formed by the equations relating the entries of $Z$ and we solve it -if possible- using a computer and the Groebner theory.

We obtain that follows. "time" indicates the time to obtain the solutions -if there are any- or to prove that there are no solutions.

$\bullet$ $n=10$. $0$ solution time<1"; $16$ solutions time=21".

$\bullet$ $n=14$. $0$ solution time<2"; $80$ solutions time=9'43".

$\bullet$ $n=18$. $0$ solution time=8".

$\bullet$ $n=20$. $0$ solution time=14"5.

The Groebner method concludes much more quickly when there are no solutions. Thus when $n$ is great, if the processor runs too long (time to be specified), then there are solutions.

$\textbf{Remark.}$ Of course, if $X,Y$ are randomly chosen, then $Z$ does not exist with a probability close to 1 - especially if $n$ is large-.